Using sub rules via Jquery Validation data-rule attributes
Referenece: https://github.com/pes10k/jquery.validate.file/blob/master/jquery.validate.file.js
$("#upload_form").validate({
                rules: {
                    example_file: {
                        fileType: {
                            types: ["pdf", "jpeg", "jpg"]
                        },
                    maxFileSize: {
                        "unit": "KB",
                        "size": 100
                    }
                }
            });

Now how to uses these rules via data-rule attributes? I have tried like data-rule-fileTye-types="['pdf', 'jpeg', 'jpg']" but it is not validating. Please help me

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This appears to be 12 years old and I see syntax errors in the Example and encounter Errors in my testing of the example. You might want to consider using a more modern plug-in for form validation. IF you insist on using this script, please provide a [mcve].

You have a typo in data-rule-fileTye... note "Tye" instead of "Type".

As this is a Plug-In to a library, you need to load the library first. Here is an example.


(function($) {
  "use strict";

  // This set of validators requires the File API, so if we'ere in a browser
  // that isn't sufficiently "HTML5"-y, don't even bother creating them.  It'll
  // do no good, so we just automatically pass those tests.
  var is_supported_browser = !!window.File,
    fileSizeToBytes,
    formatter = $.validator.format;

  /**
   * Converts a measure of data size from a given unit to bytes.
   *
   * @param number size
   *   A measure of data size, in the give unit
   * @param string unit
   *   A unit of data.  Valid inputs are "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"
   *
   * @return number|bool
   *   The number of bytes in the above size/unit combo.  If an
   *   invalid unit is specified, false is returned
   */
  fileSizeToBytes = (function() {

    var units = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"];

    return function(size, unit) {

      var index_of_unit = units.indexOf(unit),
        coverted_size;

      if (index_of_unit === -1) {

        coverted_size = false;

      } else {

        while (index_of_unit > 0) {
          size *= 1024;
          index_of_unit -= 1;
        }

        coverted_size = size;
      }

      return coverted_size;
    };
  }());

  /**
   * Validates that an uploaded file is of a given file type, tested
   * by it's reported mime string.
   *
   * @param obj params
   *   An optional set of configuration parmeters.  Supported options are:
   *    "types" : array (default ["text"])
   *      An array of file types.  This types are loosely checked, so including
   *      "text" in this array of types will cause "text/plain" and "text/css"
   *      to both be excepted.  If the selected file matches any of the strings
   *      in this array, validation passes.
   */
  $.validator.addMethod(
    "fileType",
    function(value, element, params) {

      var files,
        types = params.types || ["text"],
        is_valid = false;

      if (!is_supported_browser || this.optional(element)) {

        is_valid = true;

      } else {

        files = element.files;

        if (files.length < 1) {

          is_valid = false;

        } else {

          $.each(types, function(key, value) {
            is_valid = is_valid || files[0].type.indexOf(value) !== -1;
          });

        }
      }

      return is_valid;
    },
    function(params, element) {
      return formatter(
        "File must be one of the following types: {0}.",
        params.types.join(",")
      );
    }
  );

  /**
   * Validates that a file selected for upload is at least a given
   * file size.
   *
   * @param obj params
   *   An optional set of configuration parameters.  Supported options are:
   *     "unit" : string (default "KB")
   *       The unit of measure of the file size limit is in.  Valid inputs
   *       are "B", "KB", "MB" and "GB"
   *     "size" : number (default 100)
   *        The minimum size of the file, in the above units, that the file
   *        must be, to be accepted as "valid"
   */
  $.validator.addMethod(
    "minFileSize",
    function(value, element, params) {

      var files,
        unit = params.unit || "KB",
        size = params.size || 100,
        min_file_size = fileSizeToBytes(size, unit),
        is_valid = false;

      if (!is_supported_browser || this.optional(element)) {

        is_valid = true;

      } else {

        files = element.files;

        if (files.length < 1) {

          is_valid = false;

        } else {

          is_valid = files[0].size >= min_file_size;

        }
      }

      return is_valid;
    },
    function(params, element) {
      return formatter(
        "File must be at least {0}{1} large.", [params.size || 100, params.unit || "KB"]
      );
    }
  );

  /**
   * Validates that a file selected for upload is no loarger than a given
   * file size.
   *
   * @param obj params
   *   An optional set of configuration parameters.  Supported options are:
   *     "unit" : string (default "KB")
   *       The unit of measure of the file size limit is in.  Valid inputs
   *       are "B", "KB", "MB" and "GB"
   *     "size" : number (default 100)
   *        The maximum size of the file, in the above units, that the file
   *        can be to be accepted as "valid"
   */
  $.validator.addMethod(
    "maxFileSize",
    function(value, element, params) {

      var files,
        unit = params.unit || "KB",
        size = params.size || 100,
        max_file_size = fileSizeToBytes(size, unit),
        is_valid = false;

      if (!is_supported_browser || this.optional(element)) {

        is_valid = true;

      } else {

        files = element.files;

        if (files.length < 1) {

          is_valid = false;

        } else {

          is_valid = files[0].size <= max_file_size;

        }
      }

      return is_valid;
    },
    function(params, element) {
      return formatter(
        "File cannot be larger than {0}{1}.", [params.size || 100, params.unit || "KB"]
      );
    }
  );

}(jQuery));

$(function() {
  $("#upload_form").validate({
    rules: {
      example_file: {
        fileType: {
          types: ["pdf", "jpeg", "jpg"]
        },
        maxFileSize: {
          "unit": "KB",
          "size": 100
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
  <input type="file" name="example_file" id="example_file">
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>




Thank you. This plugin to validation library actually working great for me. But what I want is just implement via data- attributes just like data-rules-required="true" like this.
I dont know how to use it from data- attributes. Is there any way to use it  like data-fileType-types="pdf,jpg" Please let me know.

@Learner you would have to review the documentation of the Validate library: https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ and https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/ A quick look over it suggests this library does not offer that feature.
